# Node JS Reference Error "profile image not defined" on Submit. 500 error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a registration using Express Validator and for some reason, I am getting a reference error that the `profileimage` is not defined. Another thing, in my code, in declaring the variable `profileimage`, it remains grayed out (visual studio Code) and later in my code, it says that `profileimage` is declared but never read. If anyone could have a look at my code and help me spot something I might have missed, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

register.pug

```
extends layout

block content
 h2.page-header Register
 p Please register using the form below.
  if errors
   each error, i in errors
    div.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
 form(method="post", action="/users/register", enctype="multipart/form-data")
  .form-group
   label Name
   input.form-control(name="name", type="text", placeholder="Enter Name")
  .form-group
   label Email
   input.form-control(name="email", type="email", placeholder="Enter Email")
  .form-group
   label User Name
   input.form-control(name="username", type="text", placeholder="Enter User Name")
  .form-group
   label Password
   input.form-control(name="password", type="password", placeholder="Enter Password")
  .form-group
   label Confirm Password
   input.form-control(name="password2", type="password", placeholder="Confirm Password")
  .form-group
   label Profile Image
   input.form-control(name="profileimage", type="file")
  input.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", mame="submit", value="Register")
```

users.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ dest: "./uploads" });

const User = require("../models/user");

/* GET users listing. */
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("respond with a resource");
});

router.get("/register", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("register", { title: "Register" });
});

router.get("/login", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("login", { title: "Login" });
});

router.post("/register", upload.single("profileimage"), function(
  req,
  res,
  next
) {
  let name = req.body.name;
  let email = req.body.email;
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  let password2 = req.body.password2;

  if (req.file) {
    console.log("Uploading File...");
    let profileimage = req.file.filename;
  } else {
    console.log("No File Uploaded");
    let profileimage = "noimage.jpg";
  }

  // Form Validator
  req.check("name", "Name Field is Required").notEmpty();
  req.check("email", "Email Field is Required").notEmpty();
  req.check("email", "Email is not valid").isEmail();
  req.check("username", "User Name Field is Required").notEmpty();
  req.check("password", "Password Field is Required").notEmpty();
  req.check("password2", "Passwords do not match").equals(req.body.password);

  // Check errors
  let errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    res.render("register", {
      errors: errors
    });
  } else {
    let newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      profileimage: profileimage
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    });

    res.location("/");
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

user.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/nodeauth", { userNewUrlParser: true });

const db = mongoose.connection;

// User Schema
let UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  profileimage: {
    type: String
  }
});

let User = (module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema));

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback) {
  newUser.save(callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing let to var in users.js and resetting the nodejs server, I was able to get the code to work. I hope this helps someone with a similar issue.